# Progressive Web App problem when installing (no thumbnail)

Tags: json, google-chrome, frontend, manifest, progressive-web-apps

I have a PWA, but in the past couple of days (or maybe a week or two ago?) when I try to uninstall/reinstall it on my Windows 10 desktop, the icon is just some letters, not the png. 
I did make some changes to the file structure. So instead of all the files being in the root directory, they're now in the /abc/ directory.

```
{
    "name": "ABC APP",
    "short_name": "ABC APP",
    "icons": [{
        "src": "./ABC.png",
        "sizes": "192x192"
    }],
    "start_url": "/abc/index.html",
    "display":"fullscreen",
    "orientation": "landscape",
    "background_color": "green",
    "theme_color": "red"
}
```

I'm seeing no errors, I even put a favicon so that the console is showing nothing except my console message of "service worker online".

The testing I'm doing is through AWS on https, it has a manifest, serviceworker, etc.

The really weird thing is that on my macbook I'm running a slightly older build of Chrome, and when I install it there it works as expected, with the icon displaying as expected. I installed it on another Windows 10 PC, but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it was caused by an update in Chrome, but the pictures need to actually be the specified dimensions now. In my myopia induced by debugging, I failed to realize it could be a problem with other files. When I edited the thumbnail picture to the proper dimensions, the app now displays the image file and not just text.